# C# reuse instance method

Tags: c#

I have 3 classes that have instance functions that are completely identical.  Is there any way to reuse these instance methods or should I have a copy in all 3 classes e.g.

```
public class myclass1
{
    public string METHOD;
    public string RATE;
    public string QTY;

    void parseFunctionA()
    {

    }
    void parseFunctionB()
    {

    }
    void parseFunctionC()
    {

    }

}

public class MYCLASS2
{
    public string PRICE;
    public string WEIGHT;

    void parseFunctionA()
    {

    }
    void parseFunctionB()
    {

    }
    void parseFunctionC()
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: You can use an [abstract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract) class.  See example 2 on that page.

Comment: Inheritance is one option, but you could also just have those methods elsewhere.

Comment: Make a new class with only those `parseFunction...` and use it in your classes via composition.

Comment: or use an interface for composition, or use it with an extension method, or a default interface method (meh), it depends on what you want to do, why you are in this situation and what you want to achieve

Comment: @Austin - It could be a strategy pattern. Different classes designed to load from a file, or disk, or web service, etc.

Comment: @Austin I was going to make everything into 1 class but a previous question people suggested making new classes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69847749/alternative-to-multiple-list-same-length-for-storing-values

Comment: Unless your classes have private members, the simplest solution is to rewrite your functions as methods of a different class (i.e. they could be static members of `Program` along with `Main`) and have them take an instance of your class as an argument. There are a million other ways but that is the dirt simplest.

Answer (score 0):

For me two most popular ways would be to do it using:

Inheritance:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var one = new myclass1();
        var two = new myclass2();
        
        one.parseFunctionA();
        two.parseFunctionC()
    }

    // Common class can be abstract if you do want to
    // prevent it to be instantiated by itself (prevents var common = new Common())
    public class Common
    {
        // Methods made public only for example usage in Main
        public void parseFunctionA()
        {
        }
        public void parseFunctionB()
        {
        }
        public void parseFunctionC()
        {
        }
    }

    public class myclass1 : Common
    {
        public string METHOD;
        public string RATE;
        public string QTY;
    }

    public class myclass2 : Common
    {
        public string PRICE;
        public string WEIGHT;
    }
}
```

Or composition:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var common = new Common();
        var one = new myclass1(common);
        var two = new myclass2(common);
    }
    
    public class Common
    {       
        public void parseFunctionA()
        {
        }
        public void parseFunctionB()
        {
        }
        public void parseFunctionC()
        {
        }
    }
    
    public class myclass1
    {
        private Common _common;
        public myclass1(Common common)
        {
            _common = common;
        }
        
        public string METHOD;
        public string RATE;
        public string QTY;
        
        // use _common as you see fit, in methods, in properties, etc.
    }

    public class myclass2
    {
        private Common _common;
        public myclass2(Common common)
        {
            _common = common;
        }
            
        public string PRICE;
        public string WEIGHT;
        
        // use _common as you see fit, in methods, in properties, etc.
    }
}
```

There are also other methods mentioned in comments under your original post.

Mind that there are no safety features in this example.